# How to find out who is DDoSing you

Tags: router, modem, cable-modem

So I (had) a friend who now hates me and he said he would take me offline if I blocked him on Skype. I did not believe him and I said "I don't care, do your worst". Big mistake - he found out my IP address and he is now DDoSing me. I really didn't think he would be able to do it, I thought that my ISP has some sort of filter and protection against this, and that my friend was not smart enough to take me offline.

I am using an Xfinity 2 in 1 modem/router.

How can I find out the IP address of the person DDoSing me?

Comment: You don't. You complain to your ISP and have them investigate.

Comment: Specifically, you can't. A DDoS (as opposed to a DoS) involves multiple computers. You can track down the computers involved, but there's no guarantee you can track down the source of the attack because that information may no longer be known.

Comment: As ChrisInEdmonton sort of hints at.  You finding out who is performing the attack won't solve the issue, you would just have an ip address, well your ISP already has that information.  Say you do determined the ip address(es) of the attacker.  What do you hope to achieve with the information?  You as a Xfinity customer can do NOTHING about the attack, except contact them, and notify them of the problem.

Comment: Why do you need the ip address?, you know who it is, you going to ddos them back? Call your ISP! Call the college where your attacker is and complain loudly.

Comment: @kirill2485 - It is not possible for your (old) friend to determine who submitted a comment on Superuser.  Stop trusting what this person says.  While it is possible to determine the ip address of a Skype user, you are putting far to much faith, in a hostile personality.  Do yourself a favor just stop communicating with this person.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I just called Comcast and some person with a heavy accent told me to wait until my DHCP lease expires and not give out my IP to anyone. He said that there is "no further steps I can take"

Comment: This is the sucky thing about being a residential customer of a large ISP. It's very hard to get them to care.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get your ISP to care, they can identify the IP address of the attacker, determine who his Internet provider is, and complain to them. With enough pressure, the attacker's ISP will tell him to stop and threaten to disconnect his service. But this requires you to get your ISP to care enough to go to the trouble of getting his ISP to care enough.

Unfortunately, as a residential customer of a large ISP, they're just as likely to decide that you're the problem since you asked someone to attack their network.